# Mac alias in .bash_profile

Tags: macos, ubuntu

I have the following line in my .bash_profile
`alias home=“cd /Users”
when I open a terminal I get

```
`-bash: alias: /Users”: not found`
```

I have a different alias that calls a shell script and the shell doesn't complain.  What gives?

When I try to add an alias to .bashrc I get command not found

Comment: You probably copied that code from a WordPress blog? The double quotes after the `=` and at the end of the line have been converted to smart quotes. Replace them with normal straight quotes.

Comment: @duskwuff edited .bash_profile in TextEdit, actually and used double quotes.  didn't know that single quotes convert to double quotes in TextEdit

Comment: @MegaMan The problem isn't that it used double-quotes rather than single-quotes (there are differences, but they're not important here), the problem is that it converted them from plain ASCII quotes to fancy, curvy unicode quotes (which the shell doesn't recognize). This is one of the dangers of editing scripts (and config files, and...) in an editor meant for word processing. It's much better to use something intended for plain text. Like [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/), or its big brother [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/).

Comment: @GordonDavisson just gonna stick with vim :).

Comment: @MegaMan: If you're comfortable with it, vim's great for this sort of thing.